# can't draw oval in java

Tags: java, graphics

I can't draw a oval, I can't understand where I'm wrong. I have already done research but I have not found answers, sorry for the trouble.
This is my simple code:

```
public class Ball extends JPanel{


    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawOval(100, 100, 50, 50);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame game = new JFrame("Ball game!");
        game.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.setResizable(false);
        game.setLayout(null);
        game.setSize(300, 550);
        game.setLocation(400, 200);

        Ball d = new Ball();

        game.add(d);
        game.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: And what is happening and what did you expect? An oval with the same height and width is not really an oval though...

Comment: ok, but it does not appear in the JFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner content of a JFrame is its contentpane. You can just set the frame's contentpane to the panel that you want to draw, with [JFrame.setContentPane()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane(java.awt.Container)). Then your panel will be shown.

```
public class Ball extends JPanel{

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawOval(100, 100, 50, 50);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame game = new JFrame("Ball game!");
        game.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.setResizable(false);
        game.setLayout(null);
        game.setSize(300, 550);
        game.setLocation(400, 200);

        Ball d = new Ball();

        game.setContentPane(d); // <- this line
        game.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: well, you can also add the custom panel to the content pane, as he is already doing - the problem is that he has not set any size and is using the null layout

Answer (score 0):

The size of the added panel is `(0, 0)` since you are not using a Layout Manager (`game.setLayout(null)`) neither setting its size.

In that case you must set the position and **size** of any added Component:

```
Ball d = new Ball();
d.setLocation(0,0);
d.setSize(300, 500);
```

or just use a Layout Manager, e.g. the default one - BorderLayout for JFrame - and the added panel will occupy the whole area:

```
game.setResizable(false);
// game.setLayout(null);
game.setSize(300, 550);
```